# chrome.tabs not giving output in browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, console

I am working with browser's console and I want to fetch all the details of all the active tabs at the moment.What I am doing is opening browser's console and typing in this:

but this is giving me the following error:

```
VM713:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Thanks

Edit:

```
var http = require("http"),
  io = require("socket.io"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  util = require("util");

var backlog_size = 2000;
var filename = process.argv[2];
if (!filename) return util.puts("Usage: node <server.js> <filename>");
var linesCount = 0;
// -- Node.js HTTP Server ----------------------------------------------------------
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url)
  filePath = req.url
  if(filePath=="/"){
  filePath='./index.html'
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading ' + filePath);
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
  }
else
{
  if(filePath=="/client"){
       filePath = './client.html';
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading ' + filePath);
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}}
});
server.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0");
var fsTimeout
var textToSend=""
// -- Setup Socket.IO ---------------------------------------------------------
var socket = io(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
socket.on("connection", function (client) {
  

  fs.watchFile(filename, function (curr, prev) {
    
    console.log("file changed");
  
    // if (prev.size > curr.size) return { clear: true };
    // var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
    //   start: prev.size,
    //   end: curr.size,
    // });
    // stream.on("data", function (lines) {
    //   console.log(lines.toString());
    

    //   linesCount += count;
    //   console.log(linesCount);
    //   client.emit("tail", { lines: lines.toString("utf-8").split("\n") });
    // });
    if (prev.size > curr.size) return { clear: true };
    
    if(!fsTimeout){
    if(prev.ctime.getTime() != curr.ctime.getTime())
    {
      console.log("file changed")
      var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
        start: prev.size,
        end: curr.size,
      });
      stream.on("data", function (lines) {
        console.log(lines.toString());
        textToSend+=lines.toString();
        textlen=textToSend.split("\n").length;
        // count=lines.toString().split("\n").length
        // linesCount += count;
        // console.log(linesCount);
        console.log(textlen)
        if(textlen<10)
           { 
            console.log("me") 
            socket.emit("tail", { lines: lines.toString("utf-8").split("\n") });}
        else 
           { 
             console.log("client")
            socket.emit("room", { lines:  textToSend.toString("utf-8").split("\n") });  };
      });
    }
  
    fsTimeout = setTimeout(function() { fsTimeout=null }, 5000)}
    
    }
    
    
  );
});
```

This is the edited code that I used and made it working using socket.io
1

I am working on a node.js app where I am using socket.io to send data to multiple clients but the socket is only able to send data to one client i.e if I open my webpage in two tabs its not working in both the tabs but when I open just 1 tab of webpage it is able to transmit the data.I dont know why? Can someone help,Here's my code:

server.js

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is a `chrome.tabs` is a chrome extension API's object. You can not access this with chrome's dev console.

[Tabs documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query)

[Chrome Extention Quick Start Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/)